# VSTO Add-In installation without user prompt

Tags: excel, installation, vsto, silent

I build an Excel Addin with Visual Studio. The solution itself is working. 
Then I build an installer to create an MSI file. This is also working. 
I can install the MSI file as administrator and this works fine.

BUT once I start Excel and Popup is shown which is asking me if I want to install the Addin. 
In general this will be no problem. But we want to rollout this solution to many users and the expectation is, that some will click on "Not install" my mistake.

So I need a solution how it is possible that the prompt inside of Excel is not shown. So the user is not asked and the Addin is installed directly.

Does anybody has an idea or can give me an example how this is possible?

Best regards,

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

As far as my experience goes, this depends on the location where your addin is stored. I store mine under c:\Program files (x86) and never saw this message. Once I moved the location somewhere else, like "My Documents", then the box you mentioned started to pop up. 
The reason seems to be that Excel wants to warn the user about addins that were not installed from an admin account, which is the case when it is stored somehwere like "my Documents", "Downloads", or c:\ProgramData.
If you don't store your addin under c:\Program files (x86), then you also risk that a virus scanner identifies it as a threat and removes it. I saw this happening myself.